# Trouble writing array class to text file c#

Tags: c#, arrays, class

A have an array of classes.

```
  public Tasks()
  {
      tName = null;
      tDate = null;
      tPriority = null;
      tDescription = null;
  }

  Tasks[] entry= new Tasks[10];
```

Later in the program, I want to write each array of classes to a text file, one for each field.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"TaskName.txt", entry.tName);
```

It throws an error on entry.tName.

"'System.Array" does not contain a definition for 'tName' and no extension method 'tName' accepting a first arguement of type 'System.Array# could be found"

I want to be able to write the whole array for each variable, so one text file contains all the tName values, one contains all the tDate values and so on..

Any idea how to combat this?

Summary: Want to write to text files each value of the arrays, each text file only having one field in it.

Comment: Unless this is a requirement for some reason, you might consider using serialization instead (depending on what you're doing with these 4 files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new array with specific property values only:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"TaskName.txt", entry.Select(k => k.tName).ToArray());
```

The same for other properties you would like to write into file. It can even be generalized into function that expects a filename and a lambda that exposes a property.

Comment: I put that code in and got an error for 'e', so I changed it to k, and no errors are shown, should that suffice?

Thanks a lot for you help :)

Comment: @JorgeRegula yes, that would suffice.

Comment: it's probably because you have already declared someone where.. and @Andrei answer should suffice

Comment: @JorgeRegula I guess you're in a catch block and used `e` as the variable to hold your exception. Take some time to read and understand the error messages you get.

Comment: Yeah I found out it's because EventsArgs has used e

Comment: @JorgeRegula, updated to `k`, just for consistency with your code